# Common namespace naming suggestion

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, namespaces

I have a layered application with namespaces:

- `App.Core` - business layer logic services
- `App.Data` - data access layer store classes and data access objects
- `App.Web` - user interface layer

I also have business objects/DTOs. They reside in `App.Objects` namespace, but I dont like this naming convention. Why? Because this namespace will also have subnamespaces suffixed *Objects* like `App.Objects.KeywordObjects`. These subnamespaces can't be without the *Objects* suffix, because some of them will also contain classes with the same name (`App.Objects.KeywordObjects` will contain `Keyword` and `Keywords` classes).

I was thinking of changing `App.Objects` to something else. So I don't have duplicate "Objects" word. But I can't seem to find any usable word. And I don't want to use acronyms like DTO or BO.

How do you normally name your namespaces and what would you suggest I should use in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespace depth should correlate to frequency of usage. Why not put them in `App`? If your application revolves around the business objects, it makes sense to keep them at or near the root.

For a practical comparison, for many business applications the business objects are analogous to keeping common types in System. They are pervasive.

Comment: Thanks. This really makes sense, because all other layers rely on this one. So it super-positioned over them.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a fan of the guidelines in "Framework Design Guidelines" by Brad Abrams et Al, which would give you:

`YourCompany.BusinessArea` for your business objects and `YourCompany.BusinessArea.Web` for your web layer. I seem to remember there was also a guideline that an object shouldn't rely on a nested namespace (but you could rely on a parent namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- `App.Contracts`
- `App.Entities`

Giving things a good name is hard to do.  The best thing I can suggest is find something that works for you and try your best to be consistent in style and tone.   This is easier said than done.

> “When I use a word," Humpty Dumpty said in rather a scornful tone, "it means just what I choose it to mean - neither more nor less.” - [Lewis Caroll](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/when_i_use_a_word-humpty_dumpty_said_in_rather_a/214617.html)

Answer (score 0):

I normally use common acronyms freely (so I wouldn't mind using `App.BO`, personally), but if you always have the `Objects` suffix in the subnamespace I think `App.Business` reads nicely, e.g `App.Business.KeywordObjects` with that "business [something] objects" phrase. (If you don't always have the `Objects` suffix for subnamespaces then this suggestion wouldn't work as well, as things would read strangely).

Answer (score 0):

I would make the following change

```
App.Core => App.Services

App.Objects => App.Core
```

or

```
App.Objects => App.Model
```

Answer (score -1):

App.Business ?